# How do I extract substrings from string?

Tags: c#, string

I have so expression that contains numbers and plus symbols:

```
string expression = 235+356+345+24+5+2+4355+456+365+356.....+34+5542;
List<string>  numbersList = new List<string>();
```

How should I extract every number substring (235, 356, 345, 24....) from that expression and collect them into a string list?

Comment: check out string.split http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like

```
List<string> parts = expression.Split('+').ToList();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx

If there is any potential for white space around the + signs, you could so something a little more fancy:

```
List<string> parts = (from t in expression.Split('+') select t.Trim()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like:

```
string expression = "235+356+345+24+5+2+4355+456+365+356";
List<string> list = new List<string>(expression.Split('+'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this piece of code

```
string expression = "235+356+345+24+5+2+4355+456+365+356";
string[] numbers = expression.Split('+');
List<string> numbersList = numbers.ToList();
```

Comment: You don't need the new char[] { '+' }.  Just '+' works fine and is more compact.

Comment: Works because it's defined as a *params* parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Or this, a positive check for numeric sequences:

```
private static Regex rxNumber = new Regex( "\d+" ) ;
public IEnumerable<string> ParseIntegersFromString( string s )
{
    Match m = rxNumber.Match(s) ;
    for ( m = rxNumber.Match(s) ; m.Success ) ; m = m.NextMatch() )
    {
        yield return m.Value ;
    }
}
```